# How to bind localized value in Polymer 2.x

Tags: data-binding, localization

Paper toast displays a message that is bound to a string property as follows:

```
<paper-toast  text="{{message}}">
```

I need to set the message based on a key returned by the server.

Syntax to display localized value is {{localize('key')}} where key is the server response. I am not sure how to localize the key and set the message property.

Is there a way to call localize function of Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior to programmatically get localized value for a key and set the message so it can be bound to toast element?

What I am looking for is the following to work

```
text={{localize([[message]])}}
```

but it is nor working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question right or if my answer will help you. But I am using Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior the exact way you describe it. However, I only did it ones in Polymer1 and on top of that it was from a static file. I tried to adjust my answer for Polymer 2 maybe it will help you.

```
<h1>[[localize('address')]]<h1>
<paper-toast text="[[localize('address')]]">


class testElement extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior], Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'test-element'; }
      ready: function() {
        this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('locales.json'));
      }
}
```

**Update:**
This isn't pretty but I believe it would work. However I had no time to test it neither am I sure if this fits to your scenario

```
<paper-toast text="[[localize('key1')]] [[localize('key2')]]">
```

Only the given value will be bound to the text.

Comment: for line localize('address'), the key 'address' is not static. I will get the key from the server. Based on the processing done on server, it returns either key1 or  key2. I need to localize either key1 or or key2. What I am looking for is to bind parameter to localize method to a variable that I can set at run time.

Comment: I updated my answer with a rather ugly solution/idea.
Still thinking of something better.

Comment: What I am looking for is the following to work but it is not working 
       
                 text={{localize([[message]])}}>

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not working because you need to write the function like this:

```
{{localize(message)}}
```

I.e. remove the brackets.